# Azure DevOps C# SDK - How to update PR triggers for a build definition?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to enable [Comment Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#comment-triggers) for my GitHub pipelines. I want to use C# ADO sdk to do the same. However, I notice that the **Triggers field is set as `{get;}` only. Does that mean I cannot update Triggers?**

[image]

Interestingly, I **tried a workaround** where I directly called the **Rest API via Python** to update the JSON object and did a PUT request. I was able to update the triggers info **successfully**.

[image]

Wondering how to achieve the same using the C# SDK.

Comment: You can't replace the list of triggers with a new one, but you can add/remove triggers to/from the list. Have you tried `definition.Triggers.Add(myTrigger)` ?

Comment: Tried and it worked. Thanks! The question seems silly now. :) Thanks for helping out! @YanSklyarenko

Comment: There are no silly questions ;) Glad that it works now.

Answer (score 1):

@yan's suggestion worked. I removed the trigger from the Triggers list, updated it and added it back using `Triggers.Add()`.

Also verified that `UpdateDefinitionAsync(buildDef)` successfully picked up the changes I made to the `buildDef.Triggers` list.